# mysql storing right and wrong answer strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a game.  In the game, people make many choices out of 2 options.

The choice can be either right or wrong and I am storing the result of their run through the game (which can be a very large length) as a string with 1 for a right answer and 0 for wrong answers.

So for example, player `128937` will have stored in his run column the string `00010101010010001010111` as a `varchar(5000)`.

Is there a better way I can store this information in MYSQL? (I am using PHP too if that can help)

Comment: is there any point in knowing the specific data ? got the first wrong then the second right etc ? cause if you only need the sum, save 2 columns one for the amount he got right and one for the amount he got wrong

Answer (score 4):

I would create a new table (say it's called 'answers') with three columns:
question_id,user_id and  answer (which will hold values of 0/1 )

every time the player answers a question you INSERT a new entry to this table.

This way it'll be easier to maintain the sum of right/wrong answers

Comment: I think this would be very memory inneficient...I was hoping a datatype existed that I could use for the column that was better than varchar(5000)...

Comment: @David19801: question_id (INT), user_id (INT), answer (TINYINT) = 4 bytes + 4 bytes + 1 byte = 9 bytes for a row.

Comment: @Crontab: That would be per row.  so with 100 items, this would need 900 bytes, varchar would need 200?

Comment: @David19801: It's ultimately up to you - if you want to do string processing, then use a VARCHAR.  I don't know what the speed impact is on your server calculating what you need by parsing the string.  If you want to do simple stats solely using SQL queries, then do it the way alfasin suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a tinyint(1) for each option rather than using strings?

Comment: If I understand correctly I can't do this because it would need too many columns...and pulling columns would be slow...

Comment: Just as slow as pulling strings ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would make multiple tables

choices

```
id 
scenario (or other title)
```

options

```
id
choice_id
title (example: "go left" or "turn around and go home"
correct (0 or 1)
```

user_choices

```
user_id
option_id
choice_id (optional since choice_id is already in options table)
```